# How to define color resources globally in WP-App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

I want to define my colors and styles in seperate files for my WindowsPhone 8.1 Silverlight app. My files:

*Colors.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppColor1Brush">#1D8530</SolidColorBrush>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

*Styles.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="Text1Style" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppColor1Brush}" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in my App.xaml file, I try to merge those resource dictionaries:

*App.xaml*

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Resources/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But that won't work. I get the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key
>   AppColor1Brush

When I move the Color Definition from Colors.xaml into the Styles.xaml, everything works as it should. So my question: Is this even possible? Should I use something other than `StaticResource`? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference the Colors.Xaml in your Styles.Xaml as you are using the StaticResource reference there. Each xaml resource dictionary needs to have all of its references (StaticResources) available within MergedDictionaries.

Modify Styles.Xaml to:

```
<ResourceDictionary
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Resources/Colors.xaml" />
                <!-- Also add the resource reference for your font style PhoneFontSizeNormal -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="Text1Style" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppColor1Brush}" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! But I need this in reverse.. I have a global style definition (for all the same) and I want to change the color definitions with a resource dictionary. Switching the values of your answer don't work.. have you an idea how to do that?